# select the last non-empty cell in excel range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a sheet with many rows look like this

```
Castle Green     Taunton TA1 1NF             UK         
11 Bacon Ln      Moranbah QLD 4744           Australia          
40 Memory Ln     Hunter River                PE C0A 1N0      Canada     
Fidel Velazquez  Av Fidel Velázquez #3000    Col. Central    Central     64190 Monterrey     Mexico
```

I need to collect the last cell in each row in one new column. So, the new column shall look like:

```
UK
Australia           
Canada      
Mexico
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula your are looking for is:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:F2<>""),A2:F2)
```

Apply it to the range you want to extract the last non blank cell in your row.

I enter the formula in cell `G2`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In you would like to use vba, you can use the below code. The +2 inserts a blank column to separate the data.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, lCol As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For x = 2 To lRow
    ws.Cells(x, lCol + 2).Value = ws.Cells(x, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value
Next x
```